Are outlets required to be near the floor where there are shorty foundation walls?
I have friends who own a 3 year old house.  The lower part of the basement wall is concrete.  That concrete wall is about 3 feet off of the concrete floor.  If they want to add outlets to the basement, do they have to be mounted on the cement wall 12 inches above the floor, or could they be located where the framed walls begin, about 3 feet above the floor?

Anywhere from on/in the floor within 18" of the wall and below 5-1/2 feet on/in the wall meets electrical code. Where handicap accessible code applies, location is more restricted, but that's not normally the case in a private residence.
You can have outlets higher than 5-1/2 feet, or in the floor further than 18" from a wall, but they don't count towards the required outlets for a wall.
NEC 210.52 is the relevant electrical code section (USA)
So, yes, they can be 3 feet off the floor if desired. It's fairly common in workshops and garages to put them slightly above 4 feet so that 4-foot sheet goods can be leaned against the wall without blocking access to the outlets.

I see now. I misread because the floor is concrete and that wasn't asked, so it didn't register.

A friend moved a number of receptacles, particularly in hallways, up to waist height. His wife, who did the vacuuming, really appreciated not having to stoop down to plug/unplug the vacuum every week.

Also, in a workshop area, putting outlets above workbench height is great for plugging in power tools without needing to crawl underneath the workbench area to find an outlet.

Within 6 feet of the planned location of the appliance. Height is not mentioned for those, meaning that if you meet the 6 foot requirement it can be anywhere that meets that.

TL;DR Above the 3' concrete wall is fine
As I understand it, the NEC does not specify receptacle height for the required (generally every 12', but actually "within 6' of any place on the wall") general purpose receptacles. They must be below 5.5' (see NEC 210.52), and practically speaking probably 4' or lower is best for ease of access. But the typical 12" to 16" level is not in code. It is certainly quite common in workshop areas - e.g., basements - to have wall receptacles above typical countertop and table height, so 3' to 4' works quite well. In other circumstances - e.g., if you have floor-to-ceiling shelving - a floor receptacle, provided it is within 18" of the wall, can actually be better than any place on the wall.
